# Website looks fine in desktop & inspect element phone view but not on my iPhone XS?

Tags: html, css, ios, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I made a portfolio website for myself. It looks nice and I'm pretty happy with it. I always used chrome's inspect element's device toolbar (mostly iPhone X size) to get everything looking how it's supposed to for all kinds of different devices. When I opened it on my iPhone XS, some divs positioning, gradient colors and alignments were all messed up. The backdrop-filter on my header also doesn't work. However, everything looks fine through messenger's integrated browser (besides backdrop-filter) which got me thinking that Safari must be the problem. I downloaded chrome on my phone and experienced the exact same problem. What could be wrong? Is it some compatibility issue? I noticed that CSS was spitting some compatibiity errors so I fixed them, pushed the file and uploaded it to my server but it still didn't help. Everything looks perfect and scales properly in inspect element.

I've set @media max-width to 1024px.

Comment: I don't think we can help without seeing your code but just to note that Chrome on IOS is basically the same as Safari so you are unlikely to see any difference. Have you been through all the CSS checking compatability using e.g. caniuse.com?

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you! I didn't even know that such a thing as caniuse.com existed. Very useful! Turns out that yes, iOS has problems with transparency in CSS gradients which was one of my issues. iOS also didn't like position: absolute so I edited the specific div to fit right without it. Was able to fix all the problems I had. You should post your comment as an answer so I can checkmark it, or should I do it myself?

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It could be useful to others if you posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These were simply compatiblity issues. Since inspect element in Chrome doesn't actually emulate Safari running on an iPhone, that explains why I had issues in my phone but not in Chrome's inspect element mobile view. Using `caniuse.com` I found out that Safari only partially supports CSS gradients and had some unexpected behaviour when using the `transparent` tag which explains why some of my colors were messed up. Safari also didn't like `position: absolute` so I just had to position my div without it. `backdrop-filter` also required the `-webkit-` prefix to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element to be equal to the length of the screen, use "width: 100%;"
If you want the width to be equal to the width of the screen, use "height: 100vh;"

Comment: Yes, I understand this but this is not the problem here. My website is completely responsive and looks as it's supposed to even if you drag the resolution around in weird ways in inspect element. Despite this, it's still slightly broken on my phone.